# Loading the items for a combo box in advance with EXTjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have the items for a combo box being loaded from a store but what happen is when the combo box item list is to be displayed because the user clicked to 'expand it', it has to 're-load' the data from the store proxy. This causes the list to flash and become unselected, forcing the user to click the drop down another time.

Step 1 (on page load):

[image: Page is loaded, combo not visible, but firebug shows priorities is already loaded]

Clicking on the cell to edit it:

[image: cell is clicked to edit, combo box now visible, firebug shows no changes]

Clicking on the down arrow in the combobox. Again, this ajax call forces the combobox to automatically close, forcing the user to re-click the down arrow.

[image: down arrow on dropdown clicked, firebug shows another ajax call was made.]

View

```
Ext.define('AM.view.card.BacklogList', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.backlogcardlist',

    title: 'Backlog',
    store: 'BacklogCards',

    selType: 'cellmodel',
    plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 1
        })
    ],

    columns: [
        { header: 'ID', dataIndex: 'id' },
        { header: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name', field: 'textfield' },
        {
            header: 'Priority',
            dataIndex: 'priority_id',
            renderer: function(value){
                if (value==3)
                {
                    return "L";
                }
                else if (value==2)
                {
                    return "M";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "H";
                }
            },
            width: 130,
            field: {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                typeAhead: true,
                store: 'Priorities',
                displayField: 'name',
                valueField: 'id',
                listClass: 'x-combo-list-small'
            }
        }
    ]

});
```

Store:

```
Ext.define('AM.store.Priorities', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'AM.model.Priority',
    autoLoad: true,

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: 'app/data/priorities.json',
            update: 'app/data/updateUsers.json'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'priorities',
            successProperty: 'success'
        }
    }
});
```

priorities.json

```
{
    success: true,
    priorities: [
        {
            id              : 1, 
            name            : "High",
            short_name      : "H"
        },
        {
            id              : 2, 
            name            : "Medium",
            short_name      : "M"
        },
            {
            id              : 3, 
            name            : "Low",
            short_name      : "L"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Make sure you are using *queryMode* 'local', *autoLoad* true, and that you instantiate your store before attaching it to the combo. That should force it to fetch values before you show it to the end user.

Comment: Hey Twisted Pear! Thanks for the info! setting querymode to local did the trick! If you Submit it as the answer, I'll accept it asap :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe what you need to do is set queryMode: "local" on the combobox field config.

```js
field: {  
xtype: 'combobox',  
queryMode: 'local',  
typeAhead: true,  
store: 'Priorities',  
displayField: 'name',  
valueField: 'id',  
listClass: 'x-combo-list-small'
}
```

From [the Ext JS Combobox API documentation (emphasis added)](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-queryMode):

> In queryMode: 'remote', the ComboBox loads its Store dynamically based upon user interaction. 
>   This is typically used for "autocomplete" type inputs, and after the user finishes typing, **the Store is loaded**.

You have your store's autoLoad set to true, which means you shouldn't have an issue with queryModel being local, since your data should already be in the store upon creation.  I will say I haven't gone digging enough to explain the behavior, maybe someone else can elaborate the intricacies of the combobox.